# Queryselector() returns null inside javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript, module, selectors-api

I have created a module containing a variable that looks up a html element via DOM's querySelector. However, the var expoElement returns 'null'. Any thoughts?

```
var test = (function(){

    //find components
    var expoElement = document.querySelector(".expo");

    return {

        returnJow:function(){alert("the return = " + expoElement)}

    }

})();

test.returnJow();
```

Comment: `.querySelector` returns `null` for only one reason. It didn't find a match for your selector. If you have an element with that class, then perhaps you're running this before that part of the DOM is loaded.

Comment: That's exactly what's going on, how would i solve this?

Comment: While loading and executing, JavaScript blocks the part of the page that comes after if from rendering. The simplest and fastest solution is to simply put your script at the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` tag. That way the elements come above it and are able to load first.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at the HTML end.

While adding your javascript file in the HTML file make sure that you add `<script src="YOURFILE.js"></script>` tag   after the `</body>`.